# Mechanism of BELL character '\a'?

Tags: escape-characters, echo

I'm reading a book on shell programming and learning that following commands are equivalent, which beep on my Mac but don't make any sound on Ubuntu:

```
$ echo $'\a'

$ echo -e "\a"

$
```

however in both cases, terminal prompts a blank line. My questions are:

1. What's `$'\a'` here? Parameter expansion, command substitution or something else?
2. Why `echo` prints empty line as if the parameter is undefined, like for instance, in the case of

`$ echo $NONSENSE` which prompts empty line? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> don't make any sound on Ubuntu:

perhaps because your particular [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) is configured to avoid sounds, or because the `pcspkr` kernel module is unloaded, etc... You could use another terminal emulator (e.g. the old `xterm`) which should beep.

> What's `$'\a'` here?

Read the [chapter on shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) of the Bash manual.  It is called [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) (as commented by [South Parker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128402/south-parker)).

> Why echo prints empty line

the `echo` command (read more [echo(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html)...) is often a [bash shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) so (without any `-n`) it prints its expanded arguments (here the bell character) followed by a newline. But your terminal emulator don't ring the audible bell (and the bell character is *not* displayed, since it is a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character))

BTW, Apple is rumored to dislike the GPLv3+ license, so you might upgrade your  [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) to a recent version (e.g. 4.4 in august 2017) on your Apple computer.

You might read [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) for an historical approach to terminal emulators on Unix. See also [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html).

Comment: That's intensively informative, huge thanks! :)

Comment: `$'...'` isn't called "quote removal", but the `bash` manual doesn't give it a name. This form of quoting is also supported by at least the `ksh93` shell but not by `pdksh`. I believe it's an extension to the POSIX syntax.

Comment: Kusalananda I think you are right, the syntax is called ASCI-C quoting: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Comment: @SouthParker Ah, that's the name of it. Thanks for helping me remember!